# Get value from sub property

Tags: powershell

I have a list of objects ($sku) that I want to export a flattened version with selected columns.

The structure of the each object in the list is like this:

```
Name         MemberType Definition                                                                                                                 
----         ---------- ----------                                                                                                                 
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                             
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                                                          
GetType      Method     type GetType()                                                                                                             
ToString     Method     string ToString()                                                                                                          
ApiVersions  Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[string] ApiVersions {get;set;}                                                            
Capabilities Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ResourceSkuCapabilities] Capabilities {get;set;}
Capacity     Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ResourceSkuCapacity Capacity {get;set;}                                          
Costs        Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ResourceSkuCosts] Costs {get;set;}              
Family       Property   string Family {get;set;}                                                                                                   
Kind         Property   string Kind {get;set;}                                                                                                     
LocationInfo Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ResourceSkuLocationInfo] LocationInfo {get;set;}
Locations    Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[string] Locations {get;set;}                                                              
Name         Property   string Name {get;set;}                                                                                                     
ResourceType Property   string ResourceType {get;set;}                                                                                             
Restrictions Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ResourceSkuRestrictions] Restrictions {get;set;}
Size         Property   string Size {get;set;}                                                                                                     
Tier         Property   string Tier {get;set;}
```

Example:

```
ResourceType : virtualMachines
Name         : Standard_E2_v5
Tier         : Standard
Size         : E2_v5
Family       : standardEv5Family
Kind         : 
Capacity     : 
Locations    : {westeurope}
LocationInfo : {Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ResourceSkuLocationInfo}
ApiVersions  : {}
Costs        : {}
Capabilities : {MaxResourceVolumeMB, OSVhdSizeMB, vCPUs, MemoryPreservingMaintenanceSupported...}
Restrictions : {}
```

And the structure of the Capabilities I want to flatten is like this:

```
 TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ResourceSkuCapabilities

Name        MemberType Definition                    
----        ---------- ----------                    
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method     type GetType()                
ToString    Method     string ToString()             
Name        Property   string Name {get;}            
Value       Property   string Value {get;}
```

Example:

```
Name                                         Value      
----                                         -----      
MaxResourceVolumeMB                          0          
OSVhdSizeMB                                  1047552    
vCPUs                                        2          
MemoryPreservingMaintenanceSupported         True       
HyperVGenerations                            V1,V2      
MemoryGB                                     16         
MaxDataDiskCount                             4          
CpuArchitectureType                          x64        
LowPriorityCapable                           True       
PremiumIO                                    False      
VMDeploymentTypes                            IaaS       
vCPUsAvailable                               2          
vCPUsPerCore                                 2          
CombinedTempDiskAndCachedIOPS                19000      
CombinedTempDiskAndCachedReadBytesPerSecond  19000000000
CombinedTempDiskAndCachedWriteBytesPerSecond 19000000000
UncachedDiskIOPS                             3200       
UncachedDiskBytesPerSecond                   47812      
EphemeralOSDiskSupported                     False      
EncryptionAtHostSupported                    True       
CapacityReservationSupported                 False      
AcceleratedNetworkingEnabled                 True       
RdmaEnabled                                  False      
MaxNetworkInterfaces                         2
```

What I want to get out of this is something like this, but with more columns:

```
Family, Name, Location, Capabilities.vCPU, Capabilities.MemoryGB
```

My attempts to solve this doesnt work. This one is due to the fact that the subproperty name  is Name and not the vCPUs that I want to get out of it. But changing to Name wont help me either since all rows have the columnname Name.

```
$vmskus | Select-Object Family, @{n='c_Name';e={$_.Name}}, Locations, Capabilities.vCPUs, Capabilities.MemoryGB | ft
```

Expanding the property didnt help me either, it just created a lot of extra rows instead of one row.

```
$sku | Select-Object Family, @{n='c_Name';e={$_.Name}}, Locations -ExpandProperty Capabilities | ft
```

This doesnt work either since the column name is Name and not vCPUs nor MemoryGB.

```
$vmskus | Select-Object Family, @{Name = 'c_Name'; Expression = {$_.Name}}, 
                        @{Name = 'c_Locations'; Expression = {$_.Locations -join ';'}}, 
                        @{Name = 'Capabilities_vCPUs'; Expression = {$_.Capabilities.vCPUs}},
                        @{Name = 'Capabilities_MemoryGB'; Expression = {$_.Capabilities.MemoryGB}}
```

Comment: What is the type of `Capabilities`? `$sku |Get-Member Capabilities` should show, otherwise `($sku|Select -First 1).Capabilities.GetType()`

Comment: [Serializing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the object with [ConvertTo-Json -Depth -9](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) or [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) might help your further (you might also consider to add the serialized output to the question).

Comment: Name         MemberType Definition                                                                                                                 
----         ---------- ----------                                                                                                                 
Capabilities Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ResourceSkuCapabilities] Capabilities {get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those Capabilities properties using calculated properties, just like you did the 'c_name':

```
$vmskus | Select-Object Family, @{Name = 'c_Name'; Expression = {$_.Name}}, 
                        @{Name = 'c_Locations'; Expression = {$_.Locations -join ';'}}, 
                        @{Name = 'Capabilities_vCPUs'; Expression = {$_.Capabilities.vCPUs}},
                        @{Name = 'Capabilities_MemoryGB'; Expression = {$_.Capabilities.MemoryGB}}
```

For easier processing later, I'd suggest changing the dot in the column name into an underscore like I did above

<sup>I noticed 'Locations' is also an array, so I joined these into one column 'c_Locations' with a semi-colon</sup>

Comment: Good try but the name of the columns are name and not vCPU and MemoryGB